# for loop variable expressions mathematical manipulating

Tags: javascript, math, for-loop, language-agnostic

I'm writing a program in JS and im feeling i'm repeating code, which is not good. I'm trying to avoid an `if then else` block that has two similar `for loop` and re-write it without an `if then else` using just one `for loop`.

Consider this: `minimum` has value `0`. `maximum` has value `10`. if `new_value` is less than `old_value` i wanna execute a for loop from `minimum` **to** `new_value`, else i wanna execute it from `maximum` **DOWNto** `new_value`

Lets see it in action, lets say javascript (language-agnostic answers are welcome and upvoted -but will not grant you an extra cookie)

```
var minimum = 0;
var maximum = 10;
var old_value = 5;
/* var new_value = taken from user input whatever ... */

if(new_value<old_value)
{
    for(i=minimum;i<new_value;i++)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
else
{
    for(i=maximum;i>new_value;i--)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

I have a feeling these two `for loop`s are similar enough to be written as one in a mathematical approach maybe. Have tried a bit using absolute values `Math.abs()` `Math.max.apply()` but had no luck.

I don't want to set other helping variables using `if then else` to give appropriate values.

So, whats the question: **I'm wondering if this can be rewritten in one `for ... loop` without being nested in an `if then else`.**

A complete solution using built-in js functions **will** grant you an extra cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!

With this `+(old_value>new_value)` instead of getting `true/false` i am getting `1/0`. I am using the `1` and `0` as multipliers to emulate the `if then else` functionality.

lets assume

```
var minimum = 0;
var maximum = 10;
var old_value = 5;
```

for(expression1;expression2;expression3)

**For expression1:**

if new value is bigger than old value then we need minimum
if new value is smaller than old value then we need maximum

I am multiplying be zero the maximum depending the above conditions with `(maximum*(+(old_value>new_value)))`

I am multiplying by zero the minimum depending the above conditions with `(minimum*(+(old_value<new_value))`

by adding these two the sum is what i am supposed to get! `(maximum*(+(old_value>new_value)))+(minimum*(+(old_value<new_value)))`

This will give `minimum` if `new_value > old value` and `maximum` if `new_value < old_value`

**For expression2:**

while `i!=new_value;` simple. (we just have to be sure the maximum is bigger than new_value and minimum is smaller than new_value or we have an endless loop.)

**For expression3:**

if new value is bigger than old value then we need i=i **+1**

if new value is smaller than old value then we need i=i  **-1**

this

`(+(old_value<new_value)+1)+(-1*(+(old_value>new_value)+1))`

will give either 2+-1=**1** or 1+(-2)=**-1** so we simply use it in expression3 as

`i=i+(+(old_value<new_value)+1)+(-1*(+(old_value>new_value)+1))`

complete code:

http://jsfiddle.net/eBLat/

```
var minimum = 0;
var maximum = 10;
var old_value = 5;


var new_value = 3; // change this value



// if new value is bigger than old value then for loop from maximum downto new_value (dont include new value)
// if new value is smaller than old value then for loop from minimum upto new_value (dont include new value)

for(i=(maximum*(+(old_value>new_value)))+(minimum*(+(old_value<new_value)));i!=new_value;i=i+(+(old_value<new_value)+1)+(-1*(+(old_value>new_value)+1)) )
{
    alert("Iteration:"+i);  
}
```

Another question would be if this is actually better than just write two `for` in a `if then else` ... anyway i had fun. And i got the cookie :D :D

**Hope someone will find useful in some way the fact that `+true` gives `1` and `+false` gives `0` in javascript**

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Didn't see your original thing about not using the if/else with variables.  Why not do something like this then?  Just go from 0 to 10, using that value or 10 minus that value depending on the conditional.

```
for(var j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
    var i = new_value < old_value ? j : 10 - j;

    // whatever
}
```

Assign your min, max and increment as variables, define them based on your if condition and then use them in the for loop:

```
var old_value = 5, start, end, inc;

if(new_value<old_value) {
    start = 0;
    end = 10;
    inc = 1;
} else {
    start = 10;
    end = 0;
    inc = -1;
}

for( i = start;i >= start && i <= end; i += inc) {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: just posted a solution, notifying you to check it out since you tried also :D

Answer (score 0):

You could abuse of the ternary operator just for fun:

```
var minimum = 0;
var maximum = 10;
var old_value = 5;
var new_value = 7;
/* var new_value = taken from user input whatever ... */

var check =(new_value<old_value);
var foo1 = function () { console.log("foo1")  }
var foo2 = function () { console.log("foo2")  }


for(i=check?minimum:maximum;
        check?(i<new_value):(i>new_value);
        check?i++:i--)
{
    check?foo1():foo2();
}
```

Comment: haha, naughty naughty, i thought it too, but we all know it's an `if then else` there :D

Comment: just posted a solution, notifying you to check it out since you tried also :D

Comment: @Sharky It was meant to be a joke... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does the second loop *have* to iterate in reverse? If not you can simply use

```
var i0 = new_value<old_value ? minimum : new_value+1;
var i1 = new_value<old_value ? new_value : maximum+1;

for(i=i0;i<i1;++i)
{
    //whatever
}
```

**Edit**: In the light of your comment, if you can be sure that you're dealing with integers you can use

```
var i0 = new_value<old_value ? minimum : maximum;
var d  = new_value<old_value ? 1 : -1;

for(i=i0;i!=new_value;i+=d)
{
    //whatever
}
```

If not

```
var i0 = new_value<old_value ? minimum : maximum;
var d  = new_value<old_value ? 1 : -1;

for(i=i0;d*i<d*new_value;i+=d)
{
    //whatever
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it has to iterate in reverse, "downto". that's exactly the problem :(

Comment: @Sharky: OK. If my edited attempt doesn't fit the bill then you're probably better off with your original solution!

Comment: just posted a solution, notifying you to check it out since you tried also :D